# Problem using a custom .desktop file for launching Discord

Tags: launcher, .desktop

EDIT: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, latest version.

Recently I was trying to add a custom icon to the discord launcher. Unfortunately, I found out later that you can't edit snap files, which is where the usual discord.desktop file is kept. So, I set out to try and make my own...

I have the new launcher (called discord-custom.desktop) stored in a folder in my home directory.
Here is a picture of it: [image]

I copied a lot of this from the original desktop file, which has its path: /snap/discord/109/usr/share/discord/discord.desktop

Here is a picture of the original desktop file:

[image]

So thats all cool, I then saved my new custom desktop file, gave it executable permissions and dragged it into my desktop. When I try to open it however, It throws up an error message: "There was an error while launching this application"

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong to get this new desktop file to be able to launch Discord?

Comment: Maybe this will help? [Overriding .desktop files on Ubuntu snaps](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/overriding-desktop-files-on-ubuntu-snaps/6599)

Answer (score 0):

I extracted the tar file from the official download on /usr/share/discord

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Discord
StartupWMClass=discord
Comment=All-in-one voice and text chat for gamers that's free, secure, and works on both your desktop and phone.
GenericName=Internet Messenger
Exec=/usr/share/discord/Discord
Icon=/usr/share/discord/discord.png
Type=Application
Categories=Network;InstantMessaging;
Path=/usr/bin
```

copied this discord.desktop file onto /usr/share/applications
And it worked. Make sure to give the exec paths correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I copied this desktop file for discord and had no problem:

[image: desktop file for discord]